# In C, How to exit a loop based on file contents

Tags: c, database, file

I'm attempting to exit a while loop, based on file contents. File exists and is empty, or garbage filled at initialization of the program. I externally modify the file, and would like the loop to exit upon this happening based on how the file was modified.

Currently, I start a few threads, open the file that I'm reading from. Check the first byte. If it is a one, I exit, else start the loop.

When I'd like to exit. I put a one in the first byte, but it appears my file is never read again.

While loop statement and variable definition each loop looks like:

```
 while(strcmp(fileContents, "1\n") != 0){

    lengthRead = fread(fileContents, 1, size, isRecording);
    fseek(isRecording, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

I know there are probably simpler ways to exit a while loop externally, but based on the architecture of my project, the only way I can see how to control this is to exit based on file contents.

Comment: Shared memory? Sockets? Check the existence of a second file?

Comment: One suspicious thing here: You get one byte from the file using `fread()`, but then compare to two bytes (`"1\n"`) using `strcmp()`.

Comment: It does look suspicious, but fread is actually reading 1 byte at a time, for size number of bytes.

Comment: Great idea about the existence of a file. I'll attempt that shortly. Sometimes it amazes me what I don't think of!

Answer (score 1):

If your other thread is writing to the file using `fwrite()` don't forget to call `fflush()` to actually write the changes out to the file (otherwise, they can remain buffered in memory).

As Dave Jarvis mentioned, there are many other alternatives for synchronizing with another thread. For example, if you're using pthreads, pthread_cond_signal and pthread_cond_wait.

Comment: It's not the simplest system to explain, but the file is being modified by an external program. Basically just a simple python script. While debugging it appears that C never sees the change made in the file. I'm wondering if I'll need to open, read, and then close the file before redefining "fileContents" with fread(). Dave Jarvis idea of checking the existence of a file is a great idea though and I'll be seeing if that is a possible solution.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can't do the pthread thing, but the shared memory & socket options should still be feasible.